# How to add columns with "a" in the field name

Tags: python

[image]

This above is a simple example

I want to add the data which columns with "a"

```
df['a+abc+bca'] = df[['a', 'abc','bca']].sum(axis=1)
```

Although this method can be counted successfully, it is not very flexible, because if I have many columns whose field names contain "A", the drawbacks of this method will appear.

I would like to know if there is a more convenient or flexible way to achieve this? I am a novice in Python, if this seems to be a very simple question, please be able to answer it for me, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: does it need to identify "a" and capital "A" aswell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.filter(like=)`

```py
cols = df.filter(like='a').columns
df['+'.join(cols)] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   a  b  abc  bca  a+abc+bca
0  1  2    3    4          8
```

Comment: this filter method seems highly concise and intuitive then loc and [] indexing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The filter solution is easier but this works too.
a_columns = [column for column in columns if 'a' in column]
df['all_a_sum'] = df[a_columns].sum(axis=1)